# Automatically update JAR in WAR dependency lib from second project in Eclipse workspace on build/deploy

Tags: eclipse, jar, dependencies, export, build-automation

I am working on a web service with a team using SVN.

The app is (currently) divided into 2 projects in Eclipse, Project A with controllers and views, and Project B with framework support and data models.

As it currently stands, Project B is exported to a JAR and placed inside webapp/WEB-INF/lib of Project A.  This is how it exists in the SVN, and I am forbidden to change it.

I'm aware of Eclipse's deployment assembly configuration, but because the file must be pre-generated and placed in the lib folder, I am unable to use that method.  (and this is what I want to do, but not allowed)

Also, though I understand this could be done with ANT, I don't have control over the build management, so that also is not an option.

Is there a way to automatically export Project B into Project A as a JAR, inserting it into the workspace, overwriting any previous export, automatically whenever Project B is built?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be automatic, but since Project B has to build the JAR, why not put the Project B JAR file into the Project A Subversion directory.

When Project B commits to Subversion, part of the commit process would be to commit the Project B JAR.  Everyone working on Project A would do a Subversion update to get the latest Project B JAR.